# Ubuntu install from external hard drive

Tags: software-installation

I just downloaded the ISO and i don't have any blank cd's to put it on, can i install from an external hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can if your BIOS supports booting from usb and if your willing to format that drive.

You can use a program like unetbootin to create the bootable USB. This program lets you select from a whole range of linux distributions to install or just use an iso that youve already downloaded.

Then with the usb plugged into your computer, restart and enter your BIOS setup by holding delete or F10 (it will say on the screen).

If your BIOS supports USB booting the drive will show up in your boot order.